# Passing GET response Body into Variable in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, wit-ai

I need to set response data to context.forecast. I tried by using GET method inside the if loop but context becomes undefined. Is there a way to define GET function outside and just call to get the value into data variable?

Note: the location variable need to be passed into GET URL

```
getForecast({context, entities}) {
    var location = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
    if (location) {
      delete context.missingLocation;
      //TODO
      //var data = GET URL
        context.forecast = data
      })
    } else {
      context.missingLocation = true;
      delete context.forecast;
    }
    return context;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add route that uses this method?

Comment: It's not an route which calls this method. It's called by a custom method (node-wit)

Comment: just to test - write context.forecast = 'hello world' without any other conditionals. If that is working move on, debug the result of your function. Maybe you receive undefined from it.

Comment: I tried but context.forecast is not processed inside the GET method response.